# How to change the attribute value of an input using jquery

Tags: jquery, attr

I have following html structure and want to change the value of price attribute when another input is filled.

```
<dd>
    <div class="input-box additional-images imprint-images" style="height: 400px; padding-bottom: 0px; outline: medium none; overflow: hidden; width: 889px; padding-right: 0px;" tabindex="0">
        <ul id="options-788-list" class="options-list">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" price="0" value="9697" id="options_788_2" name="options[788][]" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" class="checkbox  product-custom-option">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</dd>
    <div class="color-quantity not-selected-inputs">
        <input type="text" name="custom" onkeydown="return myFunction(event);">
    </div>
```

I have tried to change price attribute by using following script but not works:

```
var quantitys = 0;
jQuery(".color-quantity > input").each(function() {
    if (this.value) {
        quantitys += (this.value) * 1;
    }

    if (parseInt(quantitys) >= "25") {
        alert("more than 25");
        jQuery("dd > .imprint-images  > ul > li > input").attr("price", "5.00");
    }
});
```

Please help me in this case.

Comment: 1) `price` is not a valid attribute for the `input` element, use a `data-*` attribute 2) `(parseInt(quantitys) >= "25")` you forgot the radix, and you're comparing an int to a string

Comment: where is the .color-quantity > input html element ? i dont see it in your html ?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan take a look on this:

jQuery("dd > .imprint-images  > ul > li > input").attr("price")).toFixed(2).("price" , "5.00");

Comment: @Ranjeet Singh See the Code now

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're attempting to do there as you've got an extra `)`, you're calling `toFixed()` on a string, and then a random, syntactically incorrect `('price', ...)` method on that string. It would really help us if you gave some more information about what output you want and under what event.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan see i have two inputs one of them have value of price="0" and i have another input on which input i want to change the value of the price attr

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<dd>
    <div class="input-box additional-images imprint-images" style="height: 400px; padding-bottom: 0px; outline: medium none; overflow: hidden; width: 889px; padding-right: 0px;" tabindex="0">
        <ul id="options-788-list" class="options-list">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" data-price="0" value="9697" id="options_788_2" name="options[788][]" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" class="checkbox  product-custom-option">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</dd>
    <div class="color-quantity not-selected-inputs">
        <input type="text" name="custom" onkeydown="return myFunction(event);">
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
var quantitys = 0;
jQuery(".color-quantity > input").each(function() {
    if (this.value) {
        quantitys += parseInt(this.value);
    }

    if (quantitys >= 25) {
        alert("more than 25");
        $("div.imprint-images > ul > li > input").attr("data-price", "5.00");
    }
});
```

Would that work for you?

Comment: Actually the Price att is dynamically created from Magneto CMS its not hard coded by my self so i can change it

Answer (score 0):

check this 
i changed **price** to **data-price** on your checkbox and 
add dummy class **update_price_element**

add class **add_price** to text field

Hpe this helps.

```js
var quantitys = 0;
 $('.add_price').blur(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value) {
   quantitys += (this.value) * 1;
  }
  if (parseInt(quantitys) >= "25") {
   alert("more than 25");
   $(".update_price_element").attr("data-price", "5.00");
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dd>
    <div class="input-box additional-images imprint-images" style="height: 400px; padding-bottom: 0px; outline: medium none; overflow: hidden; width: 889px; padding-right: 0px;" tabindex="0">
        <ul id="options-788-list" class="options-list">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" data-price="0" value="9697" id="options_788_2" name="options[788][]" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" class="checkbox  product-custom-option update_price_element">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</dd>
<div class="color-quantity not-selected-inputs">
<input type="text" name="custom" class="add_price" onkeydown="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Actually the Price att is dynamically created from Magneto CMS its not hard coded by my self so i can change it

Comment: no problem, store this price as data-attr or in a variable. then get there to add.

Comment: The main issue is that i cannot able to access the price attr